# Does iOS 4.2 change the voltage on the camera kit USB?

Tags: ios, ipad, usb

I want to use my happy hacking keyboard with ipad.

I just read an aritlce about changes on ios 4.2. One of changes I noticed was that voltage changes for camera kit on ios 4.2. I also read that USB keyboards no longer works with camera kit on ios 4.2.

Is that true?

Comment: If you have a powered usb hub your keyboard should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could have sworn I've managed to use a USB keyboard with my iPad, and it shipped to me with 4.2.1 installed. Maybe my keyboard uses less voltage (it's one of those semi-novelty foldable ones).

Perhaps you could get around this limitation with a powered USB hub?

**Update:** I've recently heard rumour of [someone working on a solution for this](http://twitter.com/#!/AppleBullet/status/13988349593260032).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true, I just connected my USB Key Board using Camera connection adapter, and it shows "Accessory unavailable, The attached accessory uses too much power".

iPad Software Version: 4.2